# render 2 index pages depend on query result - Yii framework

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-components

I need 2 index pages 1. index.php 2. index2.php

that render depend on if the query return back any result.

something like this:

```
    $sql = 'id = $id AND field LIKE ¥'%word%¥' ';

    $sql = 'id = $id and MATCH(field) AGAINST (¥'word' IN BOOLEAN MODE)';

    $query=$connection->createCommand($sql)->queryRow();

    if ($query== true) {
    $this->render('index1', array()
    } else {
    $this->render('index', array()
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem? this is feasible.

Comment: the problem this query return this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: how can this be feasible if this code will not be able to run by its own! bad syntax (not closing brackets, not putting semicolons) is popping out here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. But it seems you are getting error in lines before rendering your view.
The problem is here that you are writing bad string.
In php when you want to add variable into string directly you must use double quotation instead of single.

for example:

```
$name="test";

// RIGHT
$test="hello $name";
//WRONG
$test='hello $name';
```

if you want to add variable with a single quotation you must devide your string and variable by using dot(.);

for example:

```
$name="test";
$test='hello '.$name;
```

So this is the reason you give an error before rendering your views.

Comment: now i see this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function createCommand() on a non-object in

Answer (score 0):

dear friend beside single quotation mistake you got there and not putting `%` for LIKE commad you forgot closing brackets and semicolon! use a better IDE man!

```
if ($query== true) {
    $this->render('index1', array());
} else {
    $this->render('index', array());
}
```